# Geopandas Overlay (Intersection) Returns Zero Rows

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I created a single row GeoDataFrame with a Points `geometry` column as follows:

#### 1. Create `df`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[51.502687, -3.538329, 2242, 1, 47]],
                   columns = ["lat","long","num_of_trucks","performance","num_of_routes"]
                 )

df
```

#### 2. Create `gdf` from `df`

```py
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["lat"],df["long"]),
                                                                 crs={"init": "epsg:4326"})
gdf
```

#### 3. Reproject to CRS that uses metres

```py
gdf.to_crs(epsg=3395,inplace=True)
```

#### 4. Calculate 10KM Buffer Radius around Point and replace original `geometry` column for the Point with that for the new buffer radius Polygon

```py
gdf["geometry"] = gdf.geometry.buffer(10000)
```

The above process produced my desired single row GeoDataFrame `gdf` with a new `geometry` column  that contains a single Polygon.

I have a second GeoDataFrame called `map_selection`. This 2nd GeoDataFrame is made up of a few rows from this shapefile:https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/local-authority-districts-may-2020-boundaries-uk-buc.
Each row of this GeoDataFrame represents a UK Local Authority District (as a Polygon/Multigon in its `geometry` column). Please note that this shapefile initially used `CRS  = EPSG 27700` but I changed this to `CRS = ESPG 4326` when I loaded it as I needed to plot the Polygons in Geoviews.

Consider the following picture:

[image]

The Polygon contained in the newly produced `gdf` `geometry` column is the red circle.
Each of the blue Polygons represent the Local Authority District Polygons/Multigons contained in the `map_selection` `geometry` column.

I am trying to work out the area of each blue Polygon in `map_selection` that add together to make up the single red Polygon in `gdf`. Note that the red Polygon does not intersect all Blue Polygons but definitely intersects some.
My ultimate aim is to estimate the population of the red Polygon based on the populations of the appropriate blue Polygons.

I thought that the following would get me the intersections between the Polygons, however instead it returns zero rows:

#### 5. Reproject `gdf` CRS to match that of `map_selection`:

```py
gdf.to_crs(epsg=4326,inplace=True)
```

#### 6. Return intersection between `gdf` and `map_selection` GeoDataFrames:

```py
gpd.overlay(map_selection,gdf,how="intersection")
```

Output was zero rows, as was the output for:

```py
gpd.overlay(gdf,map_selection,how="intersection")
```

Any thoughts or suggestions as to how I could get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I plotted my 2 GeoDataFrames as suggested by @martinfleis and this showed me that my single Polygon's latitude and longitude values were inverted. Strangely they didn't appear this way when you looked at the row of the GeoDataFrame, only when plotted, which is why I didn't pick it up.

It turned out that `Step 2` of my code should have been:

```py
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["long"],df["lat"]),
                                                                 crs={"init": "epsg:4326"})
```

and not

```py
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["lat"],df["long"]),
                                                                 crs={"init": "epsg:4326"})
```

To reiterate - if you look at your `gdf` GeoDataFrame after running either of the above, the latitude and longitude values will be the same for both cases. It is only when I plotted the overlay of these 2 GeoDataFrames in Geoviews did the inversion of latitude and longitude become apparent.

My overlay now successfully returns the expected intersection rows.

Comment: Thanks, man! This 'hidden' inversion mistake nearly drove me mad xD

Answer (score 0):

You have different projections most likely. You admin boundaries are in EPSG:27700.

To make sure that you are re-projecting to the CRS of other dataframe, always pass that CRS directly.

```py
gdf.to_crs(map_selection.crs, inplace=True)
```

Comment: That's a nice tip for correct re-projecting, thank you. I tried setting the following combinations of CRS on gdf and map_selection GeoDataFrames: ESPG 27700 on both, ESPG 4326 on both, ESPG 3395 on both and ESPG 3857 on both. In each test when I attempted to perform the overlay intersection of the 2 GeoDataFrames it returns an empty DF with no rows. Do you have any other ideas what the issue could be? Thanks

Comment: If you plot both on the same axis using geopandas, do they overlap?